# How to implement something similar to c# event and delegate using PHP?

Tags: php, event-handling, porting, mediator

For studying purposes, I would like to "port" the [c# wikipedia's mediator example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) using PHP, the current example uses delagates and event. So I would like to know what could be the best approach to implement on PHP getting the same result.

A online example using c# implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fM9MD5

```
using System;
public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(string message, string sender);
public class Mediator
{
    public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;
    public void Send(string message, string sender)
    {
        if (MessageReceived != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending '{0}' from {1}", message, sender);
            MessageReceived(message, sender);
        }
    }
}
public class Person
{
    private Mediator _mediator;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(Mediator mediator, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _mediator = mediator;
        _mediator.MessageReceived += new MessageReceivedEventHandler(Receive);
    }
    private void Receive(string message, string sender)
    {
        if (sender != Name)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} received '{1}' from {2}", Name, message, sender);
    }
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        _mediator.Send(message, Name);
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var mediator = new Mediator();
        var p1 = new Person(mediator,"john");
        var p2 = new Person(mediator,"mary");
        var p3 = new Person(mediator,"lucas");
        p1.Send("hi !");
    }
}
```

And my attempt using PHP was:

```
<?php
class Mediator {
    public $MessageReceived;
    public function Send(string $message, string $sender)
    {
        if ($this->MessageReceived != null)
        {
            printf("Sending '%s' from %s", $message, $sender);
            $this->MessageReceived($message, $sender);
        }
    }
}
class Person {
    private Mediator $_mediator;
    public string $Name;
    public function __construct(Mediator $mediator, string $name)
    {
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->_mediator = $mediator;
        $this->_mediator->MessageReceived += $this->Receive;
    }
    private function Receive(string $message, string $sender)
    {
        if ($sender != $this->Name)
            printf("%s received '%s' from %s", $this->Name, $message, $sender);
    }
    public function Send(string $message)
    {
        $this->_mediator->Send($message, $this->Name);
    }
}
$mediator = new Mediator();
$p1 = new Person($mediator,"john");
$p2 = new Person($mediator,"mary");
$p3 = new Person($mediator,"lucas");
$p1->Send("hi !");
```

but I was unsuccessful. So, How to implement something similar to c# event and delegate using PHP?

Comment: When you say you were "unsuccessful", what do you mean? What went wrong? What did you try to fix it? Also, you should add PSR-12 (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) to your studying... :)

Answer (score 3):

There are no delegates and events in PHP. One way to implement the pattern is by using an [interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

Each receiver must implement the `Receiver` interface, and the mediator sends messages to all its registered receivers:

```
<?php
interface Receiver
{
    public function receive(string $message, string $sender);
}

class Mediator
{
    private $receivers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->receivers = [];
    }

    public function addReceiver(Receiver $receiver)
    {
        // Registers a receiver
        $this->receivers []= $receiver;
    }

    public function send(string $message, string $sender)
    {
        // Sends a message to all receivers
        foreach($this->receivers as $receiver)
            $receiver->receive($message, $sender);
    }
}

class Person implements Receiver
{
    private $mediator;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(Mediator $mediator, string $name)
    {
        $this->mediator = $mediator;
        $this->name = $name;
        $mediator->addReceiver($this);
    }

    public function receive(string $message, string $sender)
    {
        if($sender != $this->name)
            printf("%s received '%s' from %s\n", $this->name, $message, $sender);
    }

    public function send(string $message)
    {
        $this->mediator->send($message, $this->name);
    }
}

$mediator = new Mediator();
$p1 = new Person($mediator, 'John');
$p2 = new Person($mediator, 'Mary');
$p3 = new Person($mediator, 'Lucas');
$p1->send('Hi!');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for has already been done my a Symfony component. You can read all about it at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html

It is not implemented exactly the same way but it "the Symfony EventDispatcher component implements the Mediator and Observer design patterns to make all these things possible and to make your projects truly extensible."

You start using it by adding it to your projects dependencies

```
composer require symfony/event-dispatcher
```

The following is a simple example copied from:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MyListener
{

    public function onFooAction(Event $event)
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . '/' . __METHOD__;
        echo "<br>";
    }

}

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'foo.action' => ['onFooAction', 0],
            'bar.action' => ['onBarAction', 0],
            'baz.action' => ['onBazAction', 0]
        ];
    }

    public function onFooAction()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . '/' . __METHOD__;
        echo "<br>";
    }

    public function onBarAction()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . '/' . __METHOD__;
        echo "<br>";
    }

    public function onBazAction()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . '/' . __METHOD__;
        echo "<br>";
    }

}

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

$listener = new MyListener();
$dispatcher->addListener('foo.action', array($listener, 'onFooAction'));

$subscriber = new MySubscriber();
$dispatcher->addSubscriber($subscriber);

$dispatcher->addListener('baz.action', array($listener, 'onFooAction'));
$dispatcher->addListener('foo.action', function() {
    echo __FUNCTION__;
    echo "<br>";
});


echo "<h2>START</h2>";

echo "<h4>FOO-ACTION</h4>";
$dispatcher->dispatch('foo.action');

echo "<h4>BAR-ACTION</h4>";
$dispatcher->dispatch('bar.action');

echo "<h4>BAZ-ACTION</h4>";
$dispatcher->dispatch('baz.action');

echo "<h2>END</h2>";
```